# Asynctask .get() strange behavior

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I am building an android app in which I need to download a pdf and then view it. I have the downloading and viewing code working fine. I decided to use an Asynctask to download and show the progress. However, when it is launched, the system appears to have frozen and the dialog box doesn't come up until after the file has been downloaded. This is my onClick code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile();
    downloadFile.execute(
            "http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4130-W-SP.PDF",
            "userguide.pdf");
    try {
        downloadFile.get();
        viewPDF(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/userguide.pdf");
    } catch (Exception e) {
    }
}
```

Any idea how I could resolve this.

I have considered that I can put the viewPdf in the onPostExecute method, but this method is specifically for downloading files and this is a special case with which the pdf has to be viewed.

Thanks in advance

Edit: I solved my problem.

I added a parameter in which I would specify the of the request. This gets included in result and dependent upon it, it might get shown or not. Thanks for all the help

Comment: yes, it is frozen. because you lock the ui thread.

Comment: How do I get the thread to not lock but wait until the download is finished then? I thought that is what get did?

Comment: you. get waits (and therefore blocks, as nothing else gets executed, since your method doesn't return) until the asynctask is completed. you need to override the onPostExecute.

Comment: I mention this in the question - this is a special case but I want to be able to use this to download files in all cases. Maybe I'll add it to the parameters

Comment: override the onPostExecute so it shows it after saving it. that's what overriding is for

Comment: But I don't want to show it every single time, only certain times. I need to pass in another parameter and I am unsure how to do this

Comment: yes, that's why you would override the onPostExecute from your DownloadFile class (thus creating a child class of DownloadFile)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as doc says

**AsyncTask.html.get() :**

> Waits if necessary for at most the given time for the computation to
>   complete, and then retrieves its result.

means if you call get method for getting result from AsyncTask this will make wait in UI thread until control back from AsyncTask doInBackground method.

you can solve current issue by passing Current Activity Context to DownloadFile for Accessing method's from Activity to onPostExecute method as :

```
private class DownloadFile extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Context context;

public DownloadFile(Context context){
this.context=context;
}
 @Override
   protected void onPreExecute() {
   }
      @Override
      protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // put your PDf downloading related code here
            return null;
      }      

      @Override
      protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

        // Access Activity method here using context;
         context.viewPDF(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/userguide.pdf");      
      }

}
```

and execute `DownloadFile` on Button click as from Activity :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile(Current_Activity.this);
    downloadFile.execute(
       "http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4130-W-SP.PDF",
       "userguide.pdf");
}
```

Comment: I have considered that I can put the viewPdf in the onPostExecute method, but this method is specifically for downloading files and this is a special case with which the pdf has to be viewed.

Comment: Would I need to create a new task?

Comment: @NightStrider : means viewPDF method also downloading pdf file ?

Comment: No. I want to download it, and sometimes I want to view it but not always.

Comment: @NightStrider : then no need to create separate class to call viewPDF method just use same and start it again inside onPostExecute when previous AsyncTask finished . but this will cause infinte loop to execute AsyncTask again and again you will need to put some conditions inside onPostExecute method when start AsyncTask again or when stop it

Comment: I don't understand, sorry. How would I specify that I don't want to view the pdf?

Comment: @NightStrider: can u plz make me clear when u want download it and u want view it?

Comment: There are [will be] two buttons, one which simply downloads a pdf and the other which downloads and views it.

Comment: @NightStrider : then pass one more booelan varaible in AsyncTask constroctorand check it inside onPostExecute before starting AsyncTask again like `if(status==ture){//means download and View file click  }else{// only download button clicked}`

Comment: and they both have the same clicklistener ?

Answer (score 0):

Quick way of doing this :

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    DownloadFile downloadFile = new DownloadFile() {
        @Override
        public void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            viewPDF(getExternalFilesDir(null) + "/userguide.pdf");
        }
    };
    downloadFile.execute(
            "http://store.aqa.org.uk/qual/newgcse/pdf/AQA-4130-W-SP.PDF",
            "userguide.pdf");
}
```

This is called an anonymous class. It overrides onPostExecute from DownloadFile for this instances only.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - where do I put this, and onClick is for the Activity class, not asynctask

Comment: onClick is indeed in the Activity class. replace your onClick by this one, and it magically works ! (details : this creates a new class that adds some behaviour to the DownloadFile class. it adds the viewPDF in the onPostExecute. It is anonymous, meaning it doesn't have a name or a separated file for itself.)

Comment: but onClick is a method?????? I don't get this. I have a solution I undertstand though

Comment: yes, onClick is a method, implemented by your activity (I assume) given the prototype of the OnClickListener interface